# changing element in ngOnInit not working when changing route, but is able to access element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular project with a router. In the ngOnInits for the components I want to dynamically set a a p tags value, and an img tags href. It works on inital load, but when i change routes the values dont change. The ngOnInit function is called, but the editing of the two elements does not work.

```
document.getElementById('discord-tag').innerHTML = username;
document.getElementById('profilePicture').setAttribute('src', image_url)
```

my code is simple.

i know the ngOnInit function is working because i put some console.log statements in there to test and they run each time i click on a route link.

Comment: Do things the Angular way to avoid unexpected results. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: I added `ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.getElementById('discord-tag').innerHTML = username;
    document.getElementById('profilePicture').setAttribute('src', image_url)
  }` but it still does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you are actually modifying the DOM directly instead of using variables displaying username and img?

Comment: @AT82 there is no reason, its just that this is the only way I knew from my vanilla js web development. Could you explain how I could use variables

Comment: Img tag would be `<img [src]="image_url"`, same would be how you displaying the username we use... `<div>{{username}}</div>` as you already seem to have the variables.

Comment: Not meaning to undermine you, but these are **really** basic things in angular, please go through the "Tour of heroes" tutorial, you will learn the basics there! https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular we work with variables, manipulating the DOM directly should be the last resort, if there is no other way... BUT, usually there is an "Angular way" to handle things so that you don't need to manipulate the DOM directly. That being said, have variables in your component, which you bind to the template, so, however you get those values, assign them to variable, in OnInit, or the proper place you have them...

```
image_url!: string;
username!: string;

ngOnInit() {
  // doing stuff, getting the values... then:
  this.username = 'valueHere';
  this.image_url = 'valueHere';
}
```

Then in template use these:

```
<img [src]="image_url" />

<p>{{username}}</p>
```

As mentioned in comment, these are basic things, so I really urge you to look into the tutorial on angular.io. It's a good tutorial and you will surely learn the basics there :) https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Try ngAfterViewInit() for changing 2 elements.

Comment: I think that is right because on ngOnInit View not fully rendered.

Comment: I added `ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.getElementById('discord-tag').innerHTML = username;
    document.getElementById('profilePicture').setAttribute('src', image_url)
  }` and it didnt work. Am i doing something wrong?